# Pod's status is always ContainerCreating. . Events show 'Failed create pod sandbox'

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to create a deployment on a K8s cluster with one master and two worker nodes. The cluster is running on 3 AWS EC2 instances.  I have been using this environment for quite sometime to play with Kubernetes.  Three days back, I have started to see all the pods status to change to `ContainerCreating` from `Running`.  Only the pods that are scheduled on master are shown as `Running`. The pods running on worker nodes are shown as `ContainerCreating`.  When I run `kubectl describe pod <podname>`, it shows in the event the following

```
 Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age   From                      Message
  ----     ------                  ----  ----                      -------
  Normal   Scheduled               34s   default-scheduler         Successfully assigned nginx-8586cf59-5h2dp to ip-172-31-20-57
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume   34s   kubelet, ip-172-31-20-57  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-wz7rs"
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  4s    kubelet, ip-172-31-20-57  Failed create pod sandbox.
  Normal   SandboxChanged          3s    kubelet, ip-172-31-20-57  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
```

This error has been bugging me now. I tried to search around online on related error but I couldn't get anything specific. I did kubeadm reset on the cluster including master and worker nodes and brought up the cluster again. The nodes status shows ready. But I run into the same problem again whenever I try to create a deployment using the below command for example:

```
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --replicas=2
```

Comment: Which software defined network are you using? It would also be helpful to know the `kubelet` logs on that Node (perhaps via a pastebin or gist or such)

Comment: Also logs from your container runtime (Docker, rkt, ...)

Comment: Thank You Matthew and Jason.  I finally figured out the why it was a problem.  The security inbound rule on the EC2 instance was the culprit.  When I allowed all TCP traffic through, the problem went away.  I am using Calico as the networking solution.

Comment: I had a similar error in different context. it is quite annoying to not be able to get any more diagnostic info. is there any way to get it out of k8s ?

Answer (score 19):

This can occur if you specify a limit or request on memory and use the wrong unit.

Below triggered the message:

```
resources:
   limits:
      cpu: "300m"
     memory: "256m"
   requests:
     cpu: "50m"
     memory: "64m"
```

The correct line would be:

```
resources:
   limits:
      cpu: "300m"
     memory: "256Mi"
   requests:
     cpu: "50m"
     memory: "64Mi"
```

Comment: Nope you don't actually have to use the binary prefix e.g. `Mi`, but you must use an uppercase letter e.g. `M` instead of `m`. This is (apparently) to not confuse CPU units with RAM units.

Answer (score 1):

It might someone else, but I've spent a weekend on this until I noticed I had requested 1000 mem, insted of 1000Mi...

Answer (score 0):

I run k8s on a few DO droplets and was stuck on this very issue. No other info was given - just the `FailedCreatePodSandBox` complaining about a file I had never seen before.

Spent a lotta time trying to figure it out - the only thing that fixed the issue for me was restarting my master and each node in their entirety. That got things going instantly.

`sudo shutdown -r now`

Comment: What the reason that to restart each node? I think there is a need to consider that. Is there has the same name pod the status was pending on the node?

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen when I told my launch template it could use a transit gateway's subnet as an option. Instances that picked the wrong subnet caused one of my CoreDNS pods to get this error.